# Can't append xml node with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, insert

I have this little form that will be used to define an xml node.

[image]

and the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
    <games>
        <game id="1">
            <name>Bobs Bygg</name>
            <difficulty>5</difficulty>
            <numberOfRisks>4</numberOfRisks>
            <budget>1400000</budget>
            <targetGameTime>75</targetGameTime>
            <targetDays>85</targetDays>
            <numberOfWorkers>5</numberOfWorkers>
            <overtimeWorkers>2</overtimeWorkers>
        </game>

        <game id="2">
            <name>Bassams Bygg</name>
            <difficulty>2</difficulty>
            <numberOfRisks>4</numberOfRisks>
            <budget>14000000</budget>
            <targetGameTime>75</targetGameTime>
            <targetDays>85</targetDays>
            <numberOfWorkers>6</numberOfWorkers>
            <overtimeWorkers>1</overtimeWorkers>
        </game>
    </games>
</data>
```

So i want to make a new "game" node. I have not finished my function to get data from the inputboxes, but my function won't insert anything.

```
function addGame() {
    alert("addgame");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Data/gameData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('games').appendChild("<game id='3'><name>Bobs Bygg</name><difficulty>5</difficulty><numberOfRisks>4</numberOfRisks><budget>1400000</budget><targetGameTime>75</targetGameTime><targetDays>85</targetDays><numberOfWorkers>5</numberOfWorkers><overtimeWorkers>2</overtimeWorkers></game>");
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is where I view the XMLdata:

[image]

Comment: Use jquery method append instead of appendChild

Comment: You're not doing anything with the XML after you append to it. How can you tell whether it's working?

Comment: I have a table on the frontpage which view the data, and the table is not changing. Do I need to something after appendChild?

Comment: I might be wrong but `$.find()` is used to parse the DOM not `xml` strings

Comment: Any clues what it should be else? As you see, I want to append the node under the "games" node.